# Blockfrost API error with pycardano

Tags: transaction, blockfrost, python

I get `blockfrost.utils.ApiError: {'status_code': 400, 'error': 'Bad Request', 'message': 'Invalid address for this network or malformed address format.'}`
when using pycardano and this code

```
# Create a BlockFrost chain context
context = BlockFrostChainContext(
    "Project_id", base_url=ApiUrls.mainnet.value)
```

Same problem if I use API url directly

Is it a Pycardano issue or blockfrost?

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear:

> Invalid address for this network or malformed address format

Can you show us more of your code?

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I found the error.